# Neo4j Can we have programming features in quering graph database

Tags: neo4j

Can we Use programming features in neo4j query like as we have pl-sql in sql. I need some loops and other programming features in Cypher query.Please can anyone tell is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have two options

1. [Server Plugins](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html)
2. [Unmanaged Extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-unmanaged-extensions.html)

**Server Plugins**

- The server’s functionality can be extended by adding plugins.
- Plugins are user-specified code which extend the capabilities of the database, nodes, or relationships.
- The neo4j server will then advertise the plugin functionality within representations as clients interact via HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Pangea for Help, And i have used Server Plugin Class for getting all node from database. The code looks fine but the moment i run the code i am getting exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@fefe3f' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. at 
at GetAll.main(GetAll.java:31)
 Can you solve This exception                                                           Many Thanks  Sumit